# Regex, one string but not another

Tags: ruby, regex

Right now I have a url ending in `calculator` and another ending in `closing_cost_calculator`.  I would like to create a regular expression saying "containing the word `calculator` but not when it's on the string `closing_cost_calculator`".

Right now for "calculator by itself the regex is `/calculator/`

And for not "closing_cost_calculator" it is `^(?!.*closing_cost_calculator).*`

Comment: Use lookbehind syntax

Comment: What's wrong with the regexp you have tried?

Comment: can you rely on the character before the "calculator" is not "_" if so just add a not character class /[^_]calculator/

Comment: `(?<!closing_cost_)calculator` ...

Answer (score 0):

```
s = ["calculator", "closing_cost_calculator"]
s.collect{|x| x unless x =~ /_/ }.compact #=> ["calculator"]
```

Comment: It would be useful to add some explanation of what you have done here.